why nextjs is not allowing me to write cookies from server action in server component
Hi I'm trying to implement the logout logic, my session token is stored in the cookies, which I want to clear if the token is no longer valid. But next.js is not allowing me to do so, even so their documentation says that I can update cookies from a server action. I feel most likely the way I'm invoking server actions is the issue, if so, can u help with the better way.
This is a little confusing to me, all comments are welcomed.
import React from 'react';
import { gql } from '@urql/core';
import { cookies } from 'next/headers';
import { getClient } from '../actions';
import { redirect } from 'next/navigation';


const PokemonsQuery = gql`
    query Me {
        me {
            id
            username
            roles
            createdAt
            updatedAt
        }
    }
`;

export default async function Home() {
    const result = await getClient().query(PokemonsQuery, {}).toPromise();
    
    async function logout() {
        'use server'
        // remove cookie
        cookies().delete('access_token');
        // redirect to login page
        redirect('/login');
    }

    // if any issue happens then logout
    if(result.error && result.error.networkError){
        await logout();
    }
    
    return (
        <main>
            <h1>This is rendered as part of an RSC</h1>
            <ul>
                <div>
                    <p>id: {result.data.me.id}</p>
                    <p>username: {result.data.me.username}</p>
                    <p>roles: {result.data.me.roles.join(', ')}</p>
                    <p>createdAt: {result.data.me.createdAt}</p>
                    <p>updatedAt: {result.data.me.updatedAt}</p>
                </div>
            </ul>
        </main>
    );
}


error:
Error: Cookies can only be modified in a Server Action or Route Handler. Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/cookies#cookiessetname-value-options
    at $$ACTION_0 (./src/app/server/page.tsx:125:67)
    at Home (./src/app/server/page.tsx:41:15)


There are scenarios where you can use server actions, but not anywhere in your code, Read more.
Just create a route handler /api/access_token/route.ts:
import { cookies } from "next/headers"

export async function DELETE(req: Request): Promise<Response>() {
   cookies().delete("access_token");
   return Response.json({ message: "success" }, {status: 200}); 
}

And then call it inside your logout function:
...
async function logout() {
   // if it requires a baseUrl before the route handler path, then the baseUrl is either localhost in development or your domain in production
   await fetch(`/api/access_token`, {
      method: "DELETE"
   })
   // redirect to login page
   redirect('/login');
}
...

